# Send Email using Gmail

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I can no longer send messages from a Gmail account using Java Mail API. I suspect some changes to security are to blame.

I have this simple code:

```
public static void generateAndSendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    // Step1
    System.out.println("\n 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..");
    mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    System.out.println("Mail Server Properties have been setup successfully..");

    // Step2
    System.out.println("\n\n 2nd ===> get Mail Session..");
    getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
    generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
    generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("me@gmail.com"));

    generateMailMessage.setSubject("Greetings from Me..");
    String emailBody = "Test email using JavaMail API example.");
    generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
    System.out.println("Mail Session has been created successfully..");

    // Step3
    System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");
    Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");

    // Enter your correct gmail UserID and Password
    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "my gmail username", "my password");
    transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
}
```

I know I have the correct credentials in place of `my gmail username` and `my password` yet still I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
...
```

I have even enabled access for less secure apps, still no help.

Comment: It worked before and you haven't upgraded the version? Are you *sure* your credentials are correct?

Comment: What changed?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?